# How to fix this second tier dropdown menu background?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, responsive

I'm pretty happy with my dropdown menu, but there's one part which I can't get right.

It's about last menu item (Switch City), the 2nd tier of the dropdown extends the background of the 1st tier.

I made a Pen of it: https://codepen.io/pascalgarrix/pen/byNLEM

I'm pretty sure the problem in the CSS lies just before the media queries in this part:

```
nav ul ul ul {
position: relative;
/* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
top: -60px;
left: 270px;
```

}

If anyone could have a quick look, would be awesome!

P.S. The whole menu is based on this Pen: https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/RNeydj

Comment: Your styling targets almost all on elements, which makes it hard to understand and maintain. If you apply classnames, preferrably using BEM styling, it would be easier to help.
For the solution, I think the second tier dropdown needs `position:absolute;` at least, so it won't push it's parent open (this is what's happening)

Comment: @Esger That did the trick :) And I'll look into BEM too, but for now it's fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the 1st level nested li a max height to prevent it from growing, but still allow overflow

`nav ul li ul li:hover, nav ul li ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-height:70px;
}`